# Android: confused about how to get amplitude of a frequency generated and played by AudioTrack

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

In my app I generate list of sounds with different frequencies, for example 1000Hz, 2000Hz, 4000Hz ... for left and right channel:

```
    private AudioTrack generateTone(Ear ear) {
    // fill out the array
    int numSamples = SAMPLE_RATE * getDurationInSeconds();
    double[] sample = new double[numSamples];
    byte[] generatedSnd = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / getLatestFreqInHz()));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

    int channel;
    if (ear == Ear.LEFT) {
        audioTrack.setStereoVolume(1.0f, 0.0f);
    } else if (ear == Ear.RIGHT) {
        audioTrack.setStereoVolume(0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    return audioTrack;
}
```

I use this code to control volume:

```
        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    MAX_VOLUME = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM_MUSIC);
    MIN_VOLUME = audioManager.getStreamMinVolume(STREAM_MUSIC);
    APP_DEFAULT_VOLUME = (MAX_VOLUME + MIN_VOLUME) /2 ;

    @Override
public void setToAppDefaultVolume() {
    Timber.tag(TAG).d("Resetting to app default sound volume.");
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(STREAM_MUSIC, APP_DEFAULT_VOLUME, 0);
}

@Override
public void increaseVolume() {
    if (!isReachedMaxVolume()) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Increasing device sound volume from %d to %d", currentVolumeLevel(), currentVolumeLevel() + STEP);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolumeLevel() + STEP, 0);
    } else {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Reached the maximum device volume.");
    }
}

@Override
public void decreaseVolume() {
    if (!isReachedMinVolume()) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Decreasing device sound volume from %d to %d", currentVolumeLevel(), currentVolumeLevel() - STEP);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolumeLevel() - STEP, 0);
    } else {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Reached the preferred minimum volume");
    }

}
```

I start playing each tone (frequency) with APP_DEFAULT_VOLUME and gradually increase tone. When user confirm he/she heard specific tone with specific volume, I want to calculate it's amplitude and log it for latter so I can review user hearing ...

But i have no clue how to do so!
All solutions I found was about reading data from microphone and calculate the amplitude to visualize it on screen ...
My scenario is much simpler. I have device volume recorded, frequency is fixed and recorded, and Audio is generated dynamically and is not a file.

Will anyone help me with this scenario ?

Thanks in advance.